# Apacite and apa6 not printing annote={} and annotate={} fields

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texlive, apa6

I am trying to write an annotated bibliography, following APA format using the `apacite` and `apa6` packages.

Page 56 of the apacite manual states that the `annote` or `annotate` fields should work with `\bibliographystyle{apacann}` or `bibliographystyle{apacannx}`

However, when I compile the document using `pdflatex` and `bibtex`, I cannot get the document to print out either the `annote={}` or `annotate={}` fields.

Minimal example follows:

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[apacite]{apa6}   
\title{Minimal Example}
\shorttitle{Min. e.g.}      
\begin{document}
\nocite{carlson1984s}
\bibliographystyle{apacann}
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

Bibliography file:

```
@article{carlson1984s,
  title={What's social about social psychology? {W}here's the person in personality research?},
  author={Carlson, Rae},
  journal={Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
  volume={47},
  number={6},
  pages={1304--1309},
  year={1984},
  publisher={American Psychological Association},
  doi={10.1037/0022-3514.47.6.1304},
  annote={First annotation},
  annotate={Second annotation}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out the solution!  Apacite must be invoked in its own right, not passed as an argument to '\documentclass[apacite]{apa6}'.  The following minimal example will print the 'annote={}' field, but still no joy with 'anotate={}'.  This however is good enough!

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{apacite}   
\title{Minimal Example}
\shorttitle{Min. e.g.}      
\begin{document}
\nocite{carlson1984s}
\bibliographystyle{apacann}
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```